# Converting BigDecimal to double value

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I want to ask how to transform all my String to double with exponential.
when I use the string that length is over seven it's doing fine .

```
new BigDecimal("12345678").doubleValue() => 1.2345678E7
```

but seven and under I can't export exponential number.

```
new BigDecimal("1234567").doubleValue() => 1234567.0
```

what I want is like 1.234567E6.

Is there any way to do this? I've been searching for a while ,but got nothing.

The problem is the type I return must be double . After transforming the value under seven I can only get the value without exponential.

```
double test = new BigDecimal("1.234567E6").doubleValue() ;//output 1234567.0
```

but I need it to be 1.234567E6 and return to caller. Is that Impossible?

Comment: What do you mean? That is just formatting. The double value doesn't care how it is printed when turned into a string!

Comment: The number 1.2345678E7 is the same as 12345678.0. Note that the exponent is just something put there by the output routine (above a certain number of significant digits, the exponential form is used). It is the same number, no matter how it is displayed.

Comment: @NathanHughes: **if a double is needed, doubleValue() is the right routine**. And OP says: "The problem is the type I return must be double". Doubles can also be formatted differently, if desired.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you want to convert the value to the `BigDecimal` with exponential, you can use the `DecimalFormat`. You can also change the scale for the output value digits.

```
import java.math.*;
import java.text.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double a = new BigDecimal("1234567").doubleValue();
        String b;
        System.out.println(a);

        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
        formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(5); //<---Scale
        b = formatter.format(a);

        System.out.println(b);
     }
}
```

The output will be like:

```
1234567.0 //Unformatted Value
1.23456E6 //Formatted Value
```

Comment: OP writes: "The problem is the type I **return** must be double" (emphasis mine). So why `intValue()`? I would rather explain that exponential or plain, they remain the same value, only the textual representation is different.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks for reminding me of the data type, while it doesn't matter whether it is int or double, the `DecimalFormatter` still worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `1.2345678e7` and `12345678.0` are **exactly** the same value, only with *different **textual** representations*. You could represent `1234567.0` as `1.234567e6` too. Also **exactly** the same double, just a different way of writing it out.

The default output shows values with more than a certain number of significant digits in exponential format ("e-form"), otherwise as plain decimal format.

So you may want to change the formatting of the doubles you receive. This can be done with e.g. `DecimalFormat` or `String.format()` or similar. That does not change the doubles, only the way they are presented in a string.

Answer (score -1):

See the section about *Scientific Notation* in [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

For example,

```
    DecimalFormat scientificFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
    System.out.println(scientificFormat.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(123456L)));
    System.out.println(scientificFormat.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(1234567L)));

    scientificFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(10);
    System.out.println(scientificFormat.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(12345678L)));
```

would give you

```
1,235E5
1,235E6
1,2345678000E7
```

Change the pattern to match what you're looking for.